# iOS Cannot initialise a parameter of type'const__unsage_unretained id *'

Tags: objective-c, opencv, ios7

I am doing a project based on iOS and Opencv. I need to obtain the the coordinates of the detected contours.
What I want is to compare the edges' coordinates and the coordinates of my manually sketched points.
I try to convert the result vector of contours to NsArray. But that's where I get this error.

Here is the code:

```
-(UIImage*)findContourPoints:(UIImage*) proceesingImage
{
    cv::Mat _image = [proceesingImage CVMat];
    cv::Mat pyr, timg, gray0(_image.size(), CV_8U), gray;
    int thresh = 50, N = 11;
    cv::pyrDown(_image, pyr, cv::Size(_image.cols/2, _image.rows/2));
    cv::pyrUp(pyr, timg, _image.size());
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ ) {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);
        for( int l = 0; l < N; l++ ) {
            if( l == 0 ) {
                cv::Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
                cv::threshold(gray,gray,128,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
                cv::dilate(gray, gray, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1,-1));
            }
            else {
                gray = gray0 >= (l+1)*255/N;
            }
            cv::findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            std::vector<cv::Point> approx;

            for ( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) {
                // draw contour
                cv::drawContours(_image, contours, i, cv::Scalar(255,255,255), 1, 1, std::vector<cv::Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point());
            }
        }
    }
    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:&contours[0] count:contours.size()];

    return [UIImage imageWithCVMat:_image];
}
```

Or is there any better way for solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that! `NSArray` can store ONLY pointers to `NSObject`s. `NSArray` retains items which are stored and this operation can be done only on `NSObjects`.
Note that `contours` contains some C/C++ structures.

You have two choices: hold data in `std::vector` or hold them in `NSData` and threat this as a C-array of C-structures (3rd option is boxing each item and store it in `NSArray`, but is big useless overhead).
IMO you will gain nothing by using `Objective-c` here. I would stick with C++ as long as possible and only final result convert to `objective-c` objects.

Comment: So, how can I get coordinates from `contour`. I am a really stater for this. The trouble is I also think things in Java way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can not use for-loop as well. When I using for loop.....                   ` for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
            {
                cv::Point temp= contours[i];
            }
`  the error no viable conversion from value type...came

Comment: clean project and build it again. If this doesn't help, verify that you have added all required libraries. You should also copy paste whole error.